# How to display selected model contacts, click on one email, and pass to common email form

Tags: python, django, forms, email

Spent days reading, making relevant to my structure and combining/testing many suggestions...

Goal: Read data from contacts model, select records with Category: Sales,
display sales contacts, click on one email address, pass email address back to generic form (instead of hard-coded address - see the form below)

I am looking to make the email form recipient 'model dependent'. That way it can be flexible and the email addresses can be maintained in the DB.

...Model...

```
    from django.db import models

    class contacts(models.Model):
        category = models.CharField(verbose_name="Category", max_length=30)
        seq = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Order")
        position = models.CharField(verbose_name="Position", blank=True, max_length=50)
        name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", blank=True, max_length=100)
        email = models.CharField(verbose_name="Email", max_length=100)
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['category', 'seq'] #sets order in Django Admin
            verbose_name_plural = "contacts" #stops contactss in Django Admin
```

Django Admin Add/Change works as intended.

...Sample Data...

```
    Inquiry, 1, {Position blank}, {Name blank}, inquiry@domain.com
    Sales, 1, Sales Desk, {Name blank}, salesdesk@domain.com
    Sales, 2, Sales Manager, John Smith, johnsmith@domain.com
```

Found the following about forms, explored the self, and put them together to pass an email address to the form. This is the end goal.

The following works to set up the generic email form (except default_recepient is hard-coded):

...forms.py...

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__()
        self.default_recepient = '<pass email address here>' #Any address hard coded here goes to email form
        self.sender = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, required=True)
        self.subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
        self.message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 200, 'rows': 12}))
        self.cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

...email.html...

```
{% block body %}

  <header>
    <a href="/">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/logout/">Logout</a><br><br>
    <h1>Test Site</h1>
    <h2>Email to: {{form.default_recepient}}<h2>
  </header>

  <form action="/email/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_sender">Sender:</label>
       <input type="text" name="sender" id="id_sender" maxlength="50" />
       <label for="id_cc_myself">cc Myself:</label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="cc_myself" id="id_cc_myself" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label>
       <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_message"></label>
        Message:<br>
        <textarea name="message" id="id_message" cols=200 rows=12>
        </textarea></p>
    <p>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  {% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Found and explored various examples of using dictinaries and came up with the following:

...sales_views.py...

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from portal.models import contacts

@login_required
def support_page(request):
    contacts.object.all()
    context = RequestContext(request)
    category_list =  contacts.objects.filter(category='Sales').order_by('category', 'seq')
    context_dict = {'contacts': category_list}
    return render_to_response('portal/support.html', context_dict, context)
```

...available_contacts.html...

```
  {% if contacts %}
      {% for contact in contacts %}
          <p> 
              {{ contact.position}} <br>
              {{ contact.name }} <br> 
              Email: &nbsp; <a href="{% url email %}">{{ contact.email }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
       <strong>There are no available contacts.</strong>
  {% endif %}
```

However it will display all 3 data samples and ignores the 'Sales Only' from the objects.filter. I tried various methods like deleting from the dictionary and creating another dictionary. Same result: all 3 listing.

Started with Django Polls Tutorial and found Randall Degges on modifying the login (@login_required, and other login aspects...) Excellent job Randall!

I am not sure which direction to go from here. Some things get me so far, but not all the way. I realize I may require something like an inquiry_views.py to start the inquiry list off, but hopefully the other pieces can be static.